# how to communicate with a java method and javascript in cordova

Tags: javascript, java, cordova

I have a java method for verification of the login details-

```
public class LdapAuthentication
{
    public boolean verifyDetails(String user, String pass)
    {
        //THE CODE
    }
}
```

I want to call this `verifyDetails` method from my html page using Javascript. Is there any way of doing this?

Any help/suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can create a plugin http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Comment: @jcesarmobile - hey thanks for your suggestion. Actually am new to the phone gap and android both, so an idea whether there is any plugin already existing or do i need to create one myslef?

Comment: You have to create it yourserlf, I posted the link to the plugin development guide, I don't think there is already a plugin for the login verification